# Update Feature Update Feature

Tags: sql

My Update feature in SQL does not work.

```
 $sql = "update advert02
  set extra1 = 'Lock'
  where advert02.serialno = 208 ";
```

I have tried several versions of this code.  The serialno is unique and is the key for the table.

I get no error message but when I scroll through the table there is no change.

Comment: What happens when you query `SELECT * FROM advert02 WHERE serialno = 208`?

Comment: What database are you using?  Is it necessary to do an explicit commit.

Comment: The query looks fine so I would suspect its not actually being run. Run a DB monitor and see whats actually hitting the database.

Comment: Nothing happens.  I scroll through the table and there are no changes

Comment: I am using SQL.  I am able to create databases and tables and insert data with the various commands without using COMMIT. I will see if there is a way of adding a COMMIT command.

Comment: I am downloading my 3rd dbMonitor.  The first 2 are elaborate packages that I am unable to operate and they seem expensive.  Is there a particular dbMonitor that you would reccommend?